# Symfony assetic multiple output files based in locale

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, assetic

I'm using [symfony assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html) to manage javascripts & css assets (minify & merge all to 1 file)

```
{% javascripts
    '@CmsBundle/Resources/public/js/translations/en.js'
    '@TempBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.js' 
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/functions.js' 
    filter='?uglifyjs2'
    output='@HomeBundle/Resources/public/js/all.min.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

This code is working perfectly and output 1 file at the dir:

> @HomeBundle/Resources/public/js/all.min.js

I want to add more javascript translations files based in the requested locale

```
@CmsBundle/Resources/public/js/translations/en.js
@CmsBundle/Resources/public/js/translations/de.js
@CmsBundle/Resources/public/js/translations/fr.js
```

The expected output files with a content based in the input locale:

```
@HomeBundle/Resources/public/js/all_en.min.js
@HomeBundle/Resources/public/js/all_de.min.js
@HomeBundle/Resources/public/js/all_fr.min.js
```

I tried to use variables to generate localed files with a content based in the input locale file:

```
{% javascripts
    '@CmsBundle/Resources/public/js/translations/*'
    '@TempBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.js' 
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/functions.js' 
    filter='?uglifyjs2'
    output='@HomeBundle/Resources/public/js/all_{locale}.min.js'
    vars= ['locale']
%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

The config assetic:

```
assetic:
    variables:
        locale: [ en,de,fr ]
```

The 3 locales files was generated but with the same content and merged all locale files in the 3 output files.

I want the file `all_en.min.js` have only the content of `en.js` and other non-locale javascript files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
@CmsBundle/Resources/public/js/translations/*
```

to

```
@CmsBundle/Resources/public/js/translations/all_{locale}.min.js
```

Comment: what version of symfony and assetic are you using ? did you do the change i suggested in the second code block you provided ?